# Cascade Deleting Element from Secound List after chosse the elements from first list

Tags: development

I must do Cascade Deleting when I delete one Element in First lists, it's deletes me all bounded elements from another list's. I only must set a lookup fields at Adding Items. When I chose by editing its delete me all elements, but I don't know how to set lookap field and choose element. I find this article, but it isn't work: http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/12/add-item-to-list-with-lookup-column.html, or I cant understand. Please help.

**Edited:**

Here of my shotes  Code of items add:

```
 SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                           item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"];
                           item["Pracownik"] = properties.UserDisplayName;
                           item["Dzien"] = dzienStart;
                           item["Procenty"] = properties.AfterProperties["Procenty"];
```

I made too Look Up Column caled "ID Czas Pracy Wpisy".

**Edited 13:36**

I have got two List's:
**First list has got elements:**

```
                Contract | Worker | Day Start   | Day Stop   | Percent
                --------------------------------------------------------
 Example        Con1     | Paul   | 2012-10-12  | 2012-10-15 | 1/8
```

**Secound List should have**

```
                Contract   |   Worker   |   Day      |   Percent
                ------------------------------------------------
Should Have     Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-12 |    1/8
                Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-13 |    1/8
                Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-14 |    1/8
                Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-15 |    1/8
```

So In Secound lists I want to have a for examle name of contract which can't repeat as lookap fild, but i must set ap this value when I make a Secound List.

Comment: cant you just use event handler? delete items from second list in the 'ItemDeleted' event of first list, i did not get lookup field part, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Yes, but I must know which elements should delete, but in Items Adding Event i Cant take Id Element, because it non exists yet. So If it works By Delete Cascading only if elements is set a good lookup field, so I trying to find a lookup field method setting. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please go through this [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx) you will find everything you need to know here, go to the last of the page directly to know how to create the lookup column and if you want you can read the rest for detail information

---

If you have to accomplish the task with code

```
SPList firstList = site.Lists["FirstListName"];
SPList secondList = site.Lists["SecondListName"];
string strPrimaryCol = secondList.Fields.AddLookup("Lookupfieldname", firstList.ID, true);
SPFieldLookup primaryCol = (SPFieldLookup)secondList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(strPrimaryCol);
primaryCol.LookupField = firstList.Fields["ID"].InternalName;
primaryCol.Indexed = true;
primaryCol.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior.Cascade;
primaryCol.Update();
```

but what i dont get is how do you plan to use this code in itemadding event, what are you trying to achieve?

---

I think I got your initial question wrong you wanted to add value to lookup field in itemadding, not creating the lookup field, for that purpose you need to use SPFieldLookupValue, just use item["Look Up Field Name"]=new SPFieldLookupValue(lookupid, lookupvalue);

that's it, read the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx) documentation if you want

Comment: ok let me give you some code

Comment: Because I have Two lists. One with ranges from Date Start, to Date Stop. And Secound with Only one date, detailed a elements. I loop Items Adding to add all data From Date Start to Date Stop. And Secound list showing only detailed element's by element's.  So If I add a Detailed Element I must have got a lookap Value to delete all Bound Items. Item From First List and All Bounded Elements from secound Lists, which are bounded in first element which is deleting.

Comment: I have got a problem with this line of code `primaryCol.LookupField = firstList.Fields["Kontrakt1"].InternalName;`

Comment: But I'm vorry thjat it's not exist it Item Adding. It's Exist ?

Comment: see my update i think you need that, the code if to create the lookup field, but you have already created the lookup field, you just want to add item to it?

Comment: Yes I want to set a lookap field wchich are for example first column from the First List

Comment: use something like item["ID Czas Pracy Wpisy"]=new SPFieldLookupValue(lookupid, lookupvalue);

Comment: I updated  Question

Comment: If I puts this line: `item["ID Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(1, "Kontrakt1"); ` Debuger told me "Nie można wstawić lub zaktualizować elementu listy, ponieważ odnaleziono nieprawidłowe wartości odnośników w następujących polach listy: [ID Czas Pracy Wpisy]."

Comment: I think I something should made loop foreach and add a last item to lookup. But don't know how.

Comment: I made this code: `   SPList listaWpisy = properties.Web.Lists["Wpisy"];
          SPListItemCollection listaKontrakty = listaWpisy.Items;
          foreach (SPListItem kontrakt in listaKontrakty)
          {
          // kontrakt.ID = kontrakt.ID + 1;
           item["ID Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(kontrakt.ID, kontrakt.ID.ToString());
          }`But it shows me a lookap field before a element adding, and I want to add name of Contract of this element which are adding.